# Python Network Specific Project Recommendation

Tags: switch

I've been learning Python and since I work in networking I'd like to start writing a few scripts that I can use in my day to day work tasks with switches. 
So my question is this, what network projects have you used python in? What sort of tasks have you written scripts for? 
I'm not asking for source code, I'm interested in what projects people have done to inspire my own coding adventures!

Thanks all!

Comment: You will probably find a lot more on this at [so]. Programming is really off-topic here, but there are many network-savvy programmers there.

Comment: Hi Ron thanks for your message. Ok I'll post a question over there. Thanks!

Comment: Please check [so]'s policy for on topic questions. Your question may be too broad there.

Answer (score 2):

Backing up and copying configs to server. Automate certain config changes to adhere to standards. Scripts to copy run start on all devices at will. Finding various config entries on all devices that may need to be altered.

There are so many possibilities.

Search github and pastebin and the overflow sites for anything using:

Import netmiko
Import paramiko
Import ciscoconfparse

Scripts using any of those libraries will be network related typically and offer up ideas.